# How to join Apache Hive cubes with identical dimensions

Tags: join, hive, hql, cube

I have two cubes with the following structure:

```
-- cube 1
select
    dimension1,
    dimension2,
    sum(measure1),
    sum(measure2),
    grouping__id
  from
    table1
  group by
    dimension1,
    dimension2
    with cube
;

-- cube 2
select
    dimension1,
    dimension2,
    count(distinct measure3),
    grouping__id
  from
    table2
  group by
    dimension1,
    dimension2
    with cube
;
```

I would like to join these two cubes together so that there is a single cube with measure1, measure2, and measure3 as facts. The reason for having two separate cubes is due to the fact that the second cube involves a count distinct operation that is too expensive to run in a single step.

I have tried joining on grouping__id and nvl(a.dimension1, 0) = nvl(b.dimension1, 0) (for each of the dimensions). However, this seems to create a much larger number of rows. Even with a left join, the number of records in the joined cube is larger than the left cube.

How should two cubes with identical dimensions be joined such that no duplicate/extraneous records are created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out the difficulty simply lay in my choice of default values for NULLs; choosing 0 when 0 was a possible value for one of the dimensions led to many extraneous records. In the end, I changed 0 to -1000 (a value which I confirmed was not a value contained in the data) and joined as I had described above.

Thus, the final query was as follows:

```
select
    c1.dimension1,
    c2.dimension2,
    c1.measure1,
    c1.measure2,
    c2.measure3,
    c1.grouping__id
  from
    cube1 c1
      join cube2 c2 on c1.grouping__id = c2.grouping__id
        and nvl(c1.dimension1, -1000) = nvl(c2.dimension1, -1000)
        and nvl(c1.dimension2, -1000) = nvl(c2.dimension2, -1000)
;
```